# something is wrong with my header(Location)

Tags: javascript, php

I am very confused with this. I have a button which use JavaScript `onClick`. It should redirect to another page but it doesn't. It instead downloads the file.

**Edit**
this is all the code

```
    <?php 
$getGoogleData="SELECT * FROM markers WHERE propid=$propID";
$QgetGoogleData=$db->query($getGoogleData)or die($db->error);
    if($QgetGoogleData->num_rows==1){?>
    <p style="color:#27AB00; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">There is already Map for this project, you can't edit it but you can reamove it and make a new one<br /><br /><input type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='index.php?cid=9&proid=12&propId=<?php echo $propID?>'" value="Delete Current Map"></p>
    <?php }else{?>
    <p style="color:#CD0000; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">There are no Map for this project please make one<br /><br /><input type="button" onClick="javascript:window.location.href='index.php?cid=9&proid=11&p=<?php echo $propID?>'" value="Make Your Map"></p>
    <?php }?>
```

on the other page `proid=11`

```
case 11: header('Location:includes/pan/projects/google/face.php?p='.$p); break;
```

**I found what is wrong but still this will not solve the problem.**
I have this file in the same directory `.htaccess` which content this code.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .js

AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js

<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and I put this file because I have some php code witch will not work with the Js. without this file 
any help please.

Comment: Java **is not** Javascript

Comment: Do you have PHP installed?

Comment: `header("Location: ...");` is PHP. I see no PHP...

Comment: You are redirecting to a server path. You should redirect instead to a valid URL

Comment: @petar What's wrong with the path he gave? It's legitimate.

Comment: @Mikky, yes, but it looks like he is referring server path.

Comment: @petar My apologies, but I'm still not clear on why the path is bad.

Comment: this is the the `if(isset($_GET['propID'])){$propID=$_GET['propID'];}` the get for the `propID`

Comment: on the local server it works fine but not on the real server

Comment: @War10ck It's not bad, just a common place for a mistake if you are referring server path and it is not a valid URL

Comment: I updated my code please review

Answer (score 4):

If it downloads the PHP file then the odds are that the PHP is not being executed.

PHP is (in this context) a server side language, it needs to run through a webserver. The most likely reasons for this not to work are:

- You have no webserver
- You have not installed PHP support on the webserver
- You are running a webserver but are telling the browser to load the files with a `file://` URI instead of an `http://` URI so it isn't being used

Comment: What is wrong with this URL: `http://myserver.com.eg/includes/english/index.php?pid=2&proid=2&prodeid=1`